# Understanding proof of discontinuity for $\frac{1}{x} \sin\bigl(\frac{1}{x^2}\bigr)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, continuity

> **Example 3**
>
> Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{x} \sin\bigl(\frac{1}{x^2}\bigr)$ for $x \ne 0$ and $f(0) = 0$. Show $f$ is *discontinuous*, i.e., not continuous, at $0$.
>
> **Solution**
>
> It suffices for us to find a sequence $(x_n)$ converging to $0$ such that $f(x_n)$ does not converge to $f(0) = 0$. So we will arrange for $\frac{1}{x_n} \sin\bigl(\frac{1}{x_n^2}\bigr) = \frac{1}{x_n}$ where $x_n \to 0$. Thus we want $\sin\bigl(\frac{1}{x_n^2}\bigr) = 1$, $\frac{1}{x_n^2} = 2\pi n + \frac{\pi}{2}$, $x_n^2 = \frac{1}{2\pi n + \frac{\pi}{2}}$ or $x_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n + \frac{\pi}{2}}}$. Then $\lim x_n = 0$ while $\lim f(x_n) = \lim \frac{1}{x_n} = +\infty$.

I'm having trouble understanding the solution or what you have to show in order to prove $f$ is discontinuous. I don't understand why it starts off saying you need to find a sequence that converges to $0$ and why the givens are $x$ does not equal $0$ but it says $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: Let's go step by step, what does it mean for a function to be continuous?

Comment: @rtybase take the limit of f(x) and as x goes to c then f(c) = f(c) or the function at c is actually equal to the function at c

Comment: It also means that for any sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n = c$$ then $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) = f(c)$$

Comment: And that example is pointing to a sequence with $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n = 0$$ with $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) = +\infty \ne 0=f(0)$$
thus, the function is not continuous in $0$.

Comment: Your definition of continuous  $f(x)$ is continuous if $\lim_\limits{x\to c} f(x) = f(c)$  That is fine.  What is your definition of limit?  $\forall \epsilon>0.\exists \delta >0 : |x-c|<\delta \implies |f(x) - f(c)|<\epsilon$  What do you need to do now?  Choose an $\epsilon$ and show that there is an $x$ arbitrarily close to $0,$ such that $f(x) > \epsilon$.  How are you going to find such an $x$?  Find a sequence of $x$'s that converges to $0$ with where for every $x_n$ in the sequence $f(x_n)>\epsilon$

Answer (score 1):

If a function $f$ is continuous in $0$, that means that when $x$ is close to $0$, then $f(x)$ is close to $f(0)$. In this case we define $f(0)=0$. Now say we find a sequence $(x_n)$ which converges to $0$, which means that at a certain point, $(x_n)$ gets really close to $0$. If however the sequence $(f(x_n))$ never gets close to $f(0)$, then by definition $f$ is not continuous in $0$.